# Add values in sqlite database and output total

Tags: arrays, database, api, sqlite, express

I'm building a simple API using Express and SQLite. I managed to build the database and add data from a CSV file that looks like this:

```
|Timestamp     |Email                    |Name      |Year|Make    |Model    |Car_ID|Judge_ID|Judge_Name|Racer_Turbo|Racer_Supercharged|Racer_Performance|Racer_Horsepower|Car_Overall|Engine_Modifications|Engine_Performance|Engine_Chrome|Engine_Detailing|Engine_Cleanliness|Body_Frame_Undercarriage|Body_Frame_Suspension|Body_Frame_Chrome|Body_Frame_Detailing|Body_Frame_Cleanliness|Mods_Paint|Mods_Body|Mods_Wrap|Mods_Rims|Mods_Interior|Mods_Other|Mods_ICE|Mods_Aftermarket|Mods_WIP|Mods_Overall|
|--------------|-------------------------|----------|----|--------|---------|------|--------|----------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------|--------------------|------------------|-------------|----------------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|-----------------|--------------------|----------------------|----------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|----------|--------|----------------|--------|------------|
|8/5/2018 14:10|honoland13@japanpost.jp  |Hernando  |2015|Acura   |TLX      |48    |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |2               |4          |4                   |0                 |2            |4               |4                 |2                       |4                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |2        |0        |4        |4            |4         |6       |2               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 15:11|nlighterness2q@umn.edu   |Noel      |2015|Jeep    |Wrangler |124   |J02     |Carl      |0          |6                 |4                |2               |4          |6                   |6                 |4            |4               |4                 |6                       |6                    |6                |6                   |6                     |4         |6        |6        |6        |6            |6         |4       |6               |4       |6           |
|8/5/2018 17:10|eguest47@microsoft.com   |Edan      |2015|Lexus   |Is250    |222   |J05     |Adrian    |0          |0                 |0                |0               |0          |0                   |0                 |0            |6               |6                 |6                       |0                    |0                |6                   |6                     |6         |0        |0        |0        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 17:34|hchilley40@fema.gov      |Hieronymus|1993|Honda   |Civic eG |207   |J06     |Aaron     |0          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |2            |0               |4                 |2                       |2                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |4        |2        |2        |0            |0         |0       |2               |2       |0           |
|8/5/2018 14:30|nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it  |Nickolas  |2016|Ford    |Mystang  |167   |J02     |Carl      |0          |0                 |2                |2               |0          |2                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |2         |0        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |2           |
|8/5/2018 16:12|mdearl39@amazon.co.uk    |Martin    |2013|Hyundai |Gen coupe|159   |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |0               |0          |0                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |0         |2        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |0           |
|8/5/2018 17:00|alynamg@blogtalkradio.com|Aldridge  |2009|Infiniti|G37      |20    |J06     |Aaron     |2          |0                 |2                |2               |0          |0                   |2                 |0            |0               |2                 |2                       |2                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |2        |2        |4        |2            |2         |0       |2               |0       |2           |
|8/5/2018 16:11|abowton3k@spiegel.de     |Ambros    |2009|Honda   |Oddesy   |178   |J06     |Aaron     |2          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |0            |4               |4                 |2                       |2                    |2                |4                   |4                     |4         |2        |2        |         |6            |4         |4       |6               |4       |6           |
...
```

I used the csvtojson package to do so.

My database structure has 7 columns derived from the CSV data (Car_ID, Email, Name, Year, Make, Model, Score). The score column is the sum of all values from the Racer_Turbo column to Mods_Overall from the csv file. I managed to accurately add the car_id, email, name, year, make, and model data correctly into the database, but I can't seem to get the total to map to the score column.

Here's my code:

```
let db = new sqlite3.Database(config.database_name, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
      throw err
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to database...'.blue)
        db.run(`CREATE TABLE cars (
            car_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
            email TEXT UNIQUE,
            name TEXT,
            year INT,
            make TEXT,
            model TEXT,
            score INT
            )`,
        (err) => {
            if (err) {
                
            } else {
                csvtojson().fromFile(DATA_CSV)
                .then(data => {
                    var insert = 'INSERT INTO cars (Car_ID, Email, Name, Year, Make, Model, Score) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)';
                    for(const item of data) {
                        db.run(insert, [
                            item.Car_ID,
                            item.Email,
                            item.Name, 
                            item.Year,
                            item.Make, 
                            item.Model,
                            [item.Racer_Turbo + item.Racer_Supercharged + item.Racer_Performance + item.Racer_Horsepower + item.Car_Overall + item.Engine_Modifications + item.Engine_Performance + item.Engine_Chrome + item.Engine_Detailing + item.Engine_Cleanliness + item.Body_Frame_Undercarriage + item.Body_Frame_Suspension + item.Body_Frame_Chrome + item.Body_Frame_Detailing + item.Body_Frame_Cleanliness + item.Mods_Paint + item.Mods_Body + item.Mods_Wrap + item.Mods_Rims + item.Mods_Interior + item.Mods_Other + item.Mods_ICE + item.Mods_Aftermarket + item.Mods_WIP + item.Mods_Overall]
                        ]);
                    }
                }).catch(err => {
                    // log error
                    console.log(err);
                });
                =
            }
        });  
    }
});
```

But the output that I get when call the GET request to display the data is:

```
{
      "car_id": 48,
      "email": "honoland13@japanpost.jp",
      "name": "Hernando",
      "year": 2015,
      "make": "Acura",
      "model": "TLX",
      "score": 2.2440244242222204e+22
    },
    {
      "car_id": 167,
      "email": "nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it",
      "name": "Nickolas",
      "year": 2016,
      "make": "Ford",
      "model": "Mystang",
      "score": 2.2022000020222005e+22
    },
    {
      "car_id": 222,
      "email": "eguest47@microsoft.com",
      "name": "Edan",
      "year": 2015,
      "make": "Lexus",
      "model": "Is250",
      "score": 66600666000000000
    },
...
```

See how the score value is not an integer but some super long decimal value. Each entry should just have a whole integer value. The expected output is:

```
{
 "car_id": 48,
 "email": "honoland13@japanpost.jp",
 "name": "Hernando",
 "year": 2015,
 "make": "Acura",
 "model": "TLX",
 "score": 62
},
{
 "car_id": 167,
 "email": "nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it",
 "name": "Nickolas",
 "year": 2016,
 "make": "Ford",
 "model": "Mystang",
 "score": 20
},
{
 "car_id": 159,
 "email": "mdearl39@amazon.co.uk",
 "name": "Martin",
 "year": 2013,
 "make": "Hyundai",
 "model": "Gen coupe",
 "score": 14
}
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you considered doing the addition outside the sql statement?

Answer (score 0):

```
for(const item of data) {
  int temp = item.Racer_Turbo + item.Racer_Supercharged + item.Racer_Performance + item.Racer_Horsepower + item.Car_Overall + item.Engine_Modifications + item.Engine_Performance + item.Engine_Chrome + item.Engine_Detailing + item.Engine_Cleanliness + item.Body_Frame_Undercarriage + item.Body_Frame_Suspension + item.Body_Frame_Chrome + item.Body_Frame_Detailing + item.Body_Frame_Cleanliness + item.Mods_Paint + item.Mods_Body + item.Mods_Wrap + item.Mods_Rims + item.Mods_Interior + item.Mods_Other + item.Mods_ICE + item.Mods_Aftermarket + item.Mods_WIP + item.Mods_Overall;
  db.run(insert, [
           item.Car_ID,
           item.Email,
           item.Name, 
           item.Year,
           item.Make, 
           item.Model,
           temp
         ]);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it didn't work either, it displayed the same output that I'm having issue with.

Comment: @Stephen -- sounds like one of these has a bad value -- you need to write them out to debug where the bad data is coming from.

Comment: I took your advice, and started doing the addition by doing one column at a time. When I add item.Racer_Horsepower to the preceding 3 columns it jumps by 200 instead of adding. Values go from 0, 0, 2, then 4. It adds 0 + 0 + 2 correctly, but when when fourth value is added it outputs 224.

Comment: is it possible `item.Racer_Horsepower` is not a numeric type?  It would then cast it to a number and get a random value.

Comment: it probably was, I just went in and wrapped each item.Column I'm adding with parseInt() to make sure, and it was able to output correctly. Thank you for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

@Hogan asked me a really good question that pointed me in the right direction, and that was that one or more of the columns was not numeric in the data.

What I first did was start adding each column into the score individually to see what was happening. When I got to item.Racer_Horsepower, for whatever reason, some of the entries in the database were correctly adding the values while some where adding by the hundreds instead of as single digits. I think this is what caused the final output for each cars score to be a really odd number.

What I did was wrap each column I was adding with parseInt() when doing the addition as to ensure that the values where integers/numeric. What I ended up with was not the prettiest but got the correct outputs for each cars score.

```
for(const item of data) {
  let total = parseInt(item.Racer_Turbo) + parseInt(item.Racer_Supercharged) + parseInt(item.Racer_Performance) + parseInt(item.Racer_Horsepower) + parseInt(item.Car_Overall) + parseInt(item.Engine_Modifications) + parseInt(item.Engine_Performance) + parseInt(item.Engine_Chrome) + parseInt(item.Engine_Detailing) + parseInt(item.Engine_Cleanliness) + parseInt(item.Body_Frame_Undercarriage) + parseInt(item.Body_Frame_Suspension) + parseInt(item.Body_Frame_Chrome) + parseInt(item.Body_Frame_Detailing) + parseInt(item.Body_Frame_Cleanliness) + parseInt(item.Mods_Paint) + parseInt(item.Mods_Body) + parseInt(item.Mods_Wrap) + parseInt(item.Mods_Rims) + parseInt(item.Mods_Interior) + parseInt(item.Mods_Other) + parseInt(item.Mods_ICE) + parseInt(item.Mods_Aftermarket) + parseInt(item.Mods_WIP) + parseInt(item.Mods_Overall);
                        
 db.run(insert, [
   item.Car_ID,
   item.Email,
   item.Name, 
   item.Year,
   item.Make, 
   item.Model,
   total
 ]);
}
```